# What is the difference between "Root Directory" and "Local Directory" on Pale Moon's "about:profiles" page?

Tags: windows, windows-10, palemoon, appdata

In `about:profiles`, it says for my default profile:

```
Root Directory  C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Roaming\Moonchild Productions\Pale Moon\Profiles\blabla.default
Local Directory C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Local\Moonchild Productions\Pale Moon\Profiles\blabla.default
```

The first one, "Root Directory", appears to be the "live" dir for my profile, since my fresh cookies exist in its `cookies.sqlite`.

But then what's with the "Local Directory"?

This also confuses me in general. Why isn't everything (per-developer/company) in `C:\Users\John Doe\AppData`? What's with "Roaming" and "Local"?

Answer (score 0):

The Roaming folder is for containing data of roaming user profiles. When you log in to a domain account on another computer instead of local one, then your settings of Roaming also gets applied to that account.

And Local folder is for containing data of local user profiles. It stores the data of only the local user accounts on one computer. It is very large.

Some applications store their preferences and settings in Both Local and Roaming folder. So, they could be usable in both local and domain accounts. It makes everything more flexible.